# Authentication using Github Enterprise

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

is there a way to authenticate users using GitHub Enterprise API.

in other words can I change the url to which firebase makes the requests to to be GitHub enterprise url

Comment: Hey YGilany, GitHub enterprise is not supported by Firebase Auth. File a request for this in Firebase Support Google group.